# Change project root directory Aptana 3

Tags: file, project, aptana

When I rename the source folder of an Aptana project on disk, is there a way to change the project's path inside the IDE without deleting it and re-creating a new one?

Answer (score 2):

You could move a project directly from within the IDE:

1. In Aptana Studio, open the Navigator view using **Window** > **Show View** > **Other...** > **General** > **Navigator**;
2. In the Navigator view, right-click on the project and select **Move...**